# what does "mass-volume cars" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "big cars" or "mass-production cars"?
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mass_2

> "But we also have to resolve the issue of high manufacturing costs before we see an increased use of new, lighter-weight materials in mass-volume cars."

Source:https://www.cnbc.com/2017/08/14/japanese-auto-parts-could-soon-be-made-out-of-wood.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "mass-production cars".  In the context of "scaling up" a manufacturing process, "volume" refers to the "number of items produced" or the "rate at which items are produced".  In the context of economics, "produced" can often be replaced by "offered for sale", or "sold", or "bought".

To the extent that the number of items produced exceeds (or is less than) the number of items bought, inventories will increase (or decrease).

Answer (score 0):

It's an excellent question.  No native English speaker who owns a big car thinks that they have a "mass" car, even though they might have a massive car.

Thus, the speaker should have said, "**high**-volume cars".

Comment: Except that the term _mass-volume_ seems to be rather [common in the automotive industry](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&biw=1745&bih=920&ei=rAwCWvnKEOvajwTIqAQ&q=%22mass-volume+vehicles%22&oq=%22mass-volume+vehicles%22).

Comment: @J.R. interesting.